# Are C# Set Operations (Union, Intersect, Except, DIstinct) faster if the underlying collection is a HashSet<T> rather than a List<T>?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

For a large scale Set operations that I've been doing using `List<T>` and `Union<T>`, `Intersect<T>`.

Instead of `List<T>` to perform these LINQ Set Operations, could I just swap the underlying collection to a `HashSet<T>` and immediately see performance improvements?

Comment: Could you edit the question and include the two approaches (with code) that you would like to compare? Including also the targeted .NET platform might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those methods are all smart enough to use `O(n)` algorithms if the underlying collection doesn't already implement the set operations in an interface, so the performance difference isn't enough to worry about for most use cases.

In .NET Framework I saw a roughly 10% difference in my LINQPad-based benchmarks of each of those methods.

In .NET 6, there was no statistically-significant difference. This is unsurprising because the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) just uses an internal `Set` implementation in all of these methods, regardless of what `IEnumerable<>` it's given.

- [Union](http://share.linqpad.net/tt5jq7.linq)
- [Except](http://share.linqpad.net/i4i28d.linq)
- [Intersect](http://share.linqpad.net/q3rcas.linq)
- [Distinct](http://share.linqpad.net/hn364x.linq)